# What is the rank of a positive definite quadratic form?

Tags: linear-algebra

The text I am studying from seems to suggest that the rank of a quadratic form q on a vector space V is equal to n=dim(V), and I'm confused as to why this is the case.

Comment: Are you sure you read that correctly? Because *rank* is something defined for *matrices*, not *forms*.

Comment: There is a notion of rank for bilinear forms: one possible definition is that, (the) rank of a bilinear form is the rank of the Gram matrix with respect to a basis on $V$. As for OP's question, taking this definition of rank, the positive definiteness means that the only vector in the kernel of the matrix of $q$ is the zero vector so that it is invertible.

Comment: Yes, this is true. Over the reals, say, a quadratic form can be diagonalised with all diagonal elements 1,0, or -1; the hypothesis that it is positive definite means that all you will get are 1's, hence the rank will be maximal.

Comment: Why do we get no 0s when we diagonalise?

Comment: Because it has to be *deinite*, i.e. $q(x)\neq 0$ for all$x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The rank of a quadratic form is certainly not always the dimension of the space, otherwise the notion would be empty. But for a positive definite form, then yes, it *is* the dimension of the space, because it is non-degenerate (being anisotropic).